# Nav bar not extended to the full width of the page

Tags: html, css, django

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OFNm.jpg)

The navbar is not getting extended if scroll the page to the right. I have used the bootstrap navbar from this page. (view-source:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbars/)(second nav). I am using bootstrap.min.css. I have surfed StackOverflow for this issue. some post suggests using

```
width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 position: relative;
```

will  resolve this issue. But I could not find the same in bootstrap.min.css. Also changing the same in bootstrap.css doesn't work. Please guide me to resolve this issue.
HTML file:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Inventory</title>
  </head>
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css '%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/button.css '%}">
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">xxxxxxxxx - xxxxx</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample02" aria-controls="navbarsExample02" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample02">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <form method="POST" action="/logout/">
             {% csrf_token %}
             <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a> -->
             <input class="nav-link" id="button" type="submit" value="Logout" style="float: right">
           </form>
           <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Logout</a> -->
        </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <div class="container">
     {% block body %}

     {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>


Tha
```

nks

Comment: `width` is probably all you need. Adding it to `bootstrap.css` won't add it to `bootstrap.min.css`. Create a new stylesheet that you load AFTER `bootstrap.min.css` with the appropriate tag to apply the width.

Comment: Can't tell much without a demo. But what appears from screenshot is the below content might be overflowing the width of the body. You can check removing below content. If its due to below content, you can add a horizontal scrolling div for the below content and give `overflow-x: hidden` to the body.